# Using Scrapy for XML page

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape multiple pages from an API to practice and develop my XML scrapping. One issue that has arisen is that when I try to scrape a document formatted like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/epd7t.png and store it as an XML it fails to do so.

So within the CMD it fetches the URL it creates the XML file on my computer but there's nothing in it.

How would I fix it to echo out the whole document or even parts of it?

I put the code below:

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from doitapi.items import DoIt
import random

class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "craig"
    allowed_domains = ["do-it.org.uk"]
    start_urls = []
    number = []
    for count in range(100):
        number.append(random.randint(2000000,2500000))


    for i in number:
        start_urls.append("http://www.do-it.org.uk/syndication/opportunities/%d?apiKey=XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXXXX" %i)



       def parse(self, response):
    xxs = XmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = xxs.register_namespace("d", "http://www.do-it.org.uk/volunteering-opportunity")
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = DoIt()
        item ["url"] = response.url
        item ["name"] = titles.select("//d:title").extract()
        item ["description"] = titles.select("//d:description").extract()
        item ["username"] = titles.select("//d:info-provider/name").extract()
        item ["location"] = titles.select("//d:info-provider/address").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

Answer (score 4):

Your XML file is using the namespace "http://www.do-it.org.uk/volunteering-opportunity" so to select `title`, `name` etc. you have 2 choices:

- either use `xxs.remove_namespaces()` once and then use `.select("./title")`, `.select("./description")` etc.
- or register the namespace once, with a prefix like "doit", `xxs.register_namespace("doit", "http://www.do-it.org.uk/volunteering-opportunity")`, and then use `.select("./doit:title")`, `.select("./doit:description")` etc.

For more details on XML namespaces, see [this page in the FAQ](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-m-scraping-a-xml-document-and-my-xpath-selector-doesn-t-return-any-items) and [this page in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#removing-namespaces)

Comment: Thanks for this! Sorry if I appear like a total noob, this is my first python project and the first time I have scraped information from an XML. I'll Try this when I get home.

Comment: Hey, don't feel sorry :) XML parsing and namespaces are not straightforward, and we are all here to learn. Glad you're trying out Scrapy as your first Python project

Comment: I've tried using your code and the code within the documentation and still no luck, at least I'm getting errors now! haha The error is "Spider error processing"

Comment: exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable is also another error which pop up

Comment: Please provide the whole stack trace, and it would also help to have a sample XML document, not only the screenshot. You can use gist.github.com or Pastebin